# How to control multiDex and minifying from product flavors?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I am using following flavors to improve debug builds for devices with Android 5 and above:

```
productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
      // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
      // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
      // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prod {
      // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
      minSdkVersion 16
    }
  }
```

However not all of my devices runs under api 21+, thus I want to control multiDex and minifying. E.g.:

```
  productFlavors {
    dev {
      minSdkVersion 21
      multiDexEnabled false
      minifyEnabled false
    }
    prod {
      minSdkVersion 16
      multiDexEnabled true
      minifyEnabled true
    }
  }
```

But that's gives me:

```
Error:(44, 0) Could not find method minifyEnabled() for arguments [false] on ProductFlavor_Decorated
```

How can I combine those properties together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minifyEnabled()` propery available only in [BuildType](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html) DSL object. While `multiDexEnabled` refers to [ProductFlavor](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html) object. So if you want to combine these properties, you have to specify it in both of these objects. E.g.:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
    prod {
        minSdkVersion 16
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

For debug builds use `devDebug` build variant, for release - `prodRelease`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @maxost 
just below i have provided android developers link 
    Refer here [https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#dev-build]:

```
android {
            defaultConfig {
                ...
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
            productFlavors {
                dev {
                    // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
                    // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
                    minSdkVersion 21
                }
                prod {
                    // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
                    minSdkVersion 14
                }
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                                         'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        }
```